# Query a JSON where keys have spaces with JMESPath in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jmespath

I have a json which looks likes this:

```json
[
  {"First Name": "xyz", "Last Name": "abc", "Name": "name1"},
  {"First Name": "abc", "Last Name": "xyz", "Name": "name2"},
  {"First Name": "abcd", "Last Name": "wxyz", "Name": "name3"}
]
```

I am able to easily extract entries which do not have spaces in them. E.g.:

```
[?Name=='name1']
```

Which gives:

```json
[
  { "First Name": "xyz", "Last Name": "abc", "Name": "name1" }
]
```

However, I am unable to get entries where the keys have spaces in them. e.g.:

- `[?First Name =='xyz']` results in `Syntax error: expected Rbracket, got: UnquotedIdentifier`
- `[?'First Name' =='xyz']` results in `[]`

Am I missing something here?

JMESPath version used in Python:

```py
>>> jmespath.__version__
'0.10.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key in the query should be in **double** quotes:

```
[?"First Name" == 'xyz']
```

This is because single quotes and doubles quotes do not have the same meaning in JMESPath.

- single quotes are [*raw string literals*](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals), so, if you are using them you are trying to assess that the string `First Name` is equal to the string `xyz`, which will, obviously never ever be true
- double quotes on the other hand are for identifiers:

  > An identifier can also be quoted. This is necessary when an identifier has characters not specified in the `unquoted-string` grammar rule. In this situation, an identifier is specified with a double quote, followed by any number of `unescaped-char` or `escaped-char` characters, followed by a double quote. The `quoted-string` rule is the same grammar rule as a JSON string, so any valid string can be used between double quoted, include JSON supported escape sequences, and six character unicode escape sequences.

  <sup>*Source: https://jmespath.org/specification.html#identifiers*</sup>